# Create information window from android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm studying to create an android keyboard. I have read some blogs and been successful to create a custom keyboard in android. What I want to do next is opening a window of text while pressing on 'user' imageView (on the top of normal keyboard). The user can choose his saved text to write into an editText of an another app. I tried to open popupWindow/Dialog to contain the user's text, but I have always error "unable to add Window" :(. I understand the meaning of the error is that I don't have a good context for my popupWindow/dialog. Do you have any idea about how to do it? Here below is the code of my keyboard.

Class IME:

```
public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {
private KeyboardView kv;
private Keyboard keyboard;
private boolean caps = false;
private String insertText = "Your text you want to write";
@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    final View root = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);

    final ImageView ivKeyboard = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.ivKeyboard);

    ivKeyboard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(view.getContext());
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
            dialog.setTitle("Copy your text:");
            TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            textView.setText(insertText);
            Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(insertText, insertText.length());
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
            //whatever you want to do...
        }
    });

    kv = (KeyboardView) root.findViewById(R.id.keyboard);

    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onPress(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onRelease(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    playClick(primaryCode);

    switch(primaryCode){
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
        default:
            char code = (char)primaryCode;
            if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            }
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
    }

}

@Override
public void onText(CharSequence charSequence) {

}

@Override
public void swipeLeft() {

}

@Override
public void swipeRight() {

}

@Override
public void swipeDown() {

}

@Override
public void swipeUp() {

}

private void playClick(int keyCode){
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    switch(keyCode){
        case 32:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
        case 10:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
            break;
        default: am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
    }
}
```

}

Any suggestion is appreciated, 
Thank you!